# Pagination on PrimeNG using Data Table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I need to automatically navigate through the pages when the maximum rows number per page is reached.

I have a dataTable and an array that are the records. I added two items into my array and defined the property [rows] as 1.

**.html**

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="cars" [rows]="1" [paginator]="true"></p-dataTable>
```

**.ts**

```
this.cars.push(new Car("A", "B", "C", "D"));
this.cars.push(new Car("E", "F", "G", "H"));
```

Also, did the following code when adding a new car when clicking on a button:

**.ts**

```
@ViewChild('dt') data: DataTable;

// before this line is all the logic to add the car in the list
if ((this.cars.length - 1) %  this.data.rows === 0) {
  this.data.paginate();
}
```

When the first row of a new page is added, it executes the paginate but nothing happens.

What can I do?

Comment: which version of angular and primeng are you using? and why are you calling paginate() manually?

Comment: I am using the version 5.0.3 and primeng 5.2.3.

Because when I add a new record that creates a new page of rows I want the table to paginate automatically to the new page.

For example: my table supports 10 rows per page, when I add the 11th row, it will create a new page and I want the table to go directly to this new page, not stay in the current.